# Non-WordPress page alongside WordPress installation on Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a WordPress running fine.  But now I want to have a completely separate HTML page (with its own subfolder of images and JS) alongside it.

So, my WordPress site is somewhere like mysite.com, and I want mysite.com/ebook to go to a separate directory on my server (and not be handled by WordPress at all).

My config is below, and it's *almost* working.

```
server {    
    server_name mysite.local;
    root F:/code/mysite/wordpress/;
    index index.php;

    #These includes came from http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx
    include f:/code/mysite/dev-ops/nginx/dev/global/restrictions.conf;
    include f:/code/mysite/dev-ops/nginx/dev/global/wordpress.conf;

    location /ebook/ {
        root        F:/code/mysite/other_public/;
        index           index.html;
    }

}
```

The only problem seems to be this section of `wordpress.conf` from http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx.

```
# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}
```

If I remove this section, my subsite works fine.

But I'd rather not remove it since it was recommended by Nginx.  Is there a way for me to accomplish my goal *and* accomplish whatever Nginx was recommending here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do there. I have worked with many WP sites and have not seen what it is you're working with.  So forgive me if I am missing the bigger picture.

You can safely run a secondary site side-by-side with wordpress. That is it. You'll need to make sure you have 404 errors (no missing pages, images, etc).  That is what the code is doing above.

Start simple. Create subdirectory (subfolder):

```
root/[site]/wp-content (you should have)
root/[site]/wp-admin (you should have)
root/[site]/MyNewSite (you will add).
```

Then add index.html (apache) into MyNewSite.  You are good to go.

Comment: I am using Nginx (not Apache).  Putting my `ebook` folder as a sibling of `wp-content` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the official `global/wordpress.conf` file (that I'd copied from http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) to have the 2nd location block nested within the first, like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
           access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;               
    }
}
```

This seemed to work.  I tested by temporarily adding `rewrite .jpg .jxg;` into the inner location block and seeing what happened to jpg images.

Another approach that I thought of (but didn't prefer) was: I could have left the location blocks un-nested but edited the 2nd one to be: `^(?!\/ebook).+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$`